# Unable to access Grafana UI on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, grafana

I have a K8S cluster setup on openstack using the COREOS guide.

I am getting following error while accessing the GRAFANA UI on [http://master-ip:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/](http://%3Cmaster%3E:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/)

```
Error: 'dial tcp 172.17.0.5:3000: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.17.0.5:3000/'
```

I can access the InfluxDB UI at the influxdb-nodeip:8083.

I can curl to **172.17.0.5:3000** from within the node.

Steps I followed:

1. Created the K8S cluster with 1 master and 1 node.
2. Created namespace
3. Setup DNS
4. Confirmed  DNS is working using busybox example.
5. Setup InfluxDB and Grafana.

**Grafana container log**

```
2016/04/21 14:53:33 [I] Listen: http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
.Grafana is up and running.
Creating default influxdb datasource...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   242  100    37  100   205   3274  18143 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18636
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: grafana_sess=cd44a6ed54b863df; Path=/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana; HttpOnly
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 14:53:34 GMT
Content-Length: 37

{"id":1,"message":"Datasource added"}
Importing default dashboards...
Importing /dashboards/cluster.json ...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 71639  100    49  100 71590    539   769k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  776k
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

**Cluster-info**

```
cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at <master>:8080
Heapster is running at <master>:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
KubeDNS is running at <master>:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
Grafana is running at <master>:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
InfluxDB is running at <master>:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb
```

**version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.8", GitCommit:"a8af33dc07ee08defa2d503f81e7deea32dd1d3b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.8", GitCommit:"a8af33dc07ee08defa2d503f81e7deea32dd1d3b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

**Node iptables: sudo iptables -n -t nat -L**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* handle ClusterIPs; NOTE: this must be before the NodePort rul                    es */
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
KUBE-NODEPORT-CONTAINER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL /* handle service NodePorts; NOTE                    : this must be the last rule in the chain */

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-PORTALS-HOST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* handle ClusterIPs; NOTE: this must be before the NodePort rules */
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
KUBE-NODEPORT-HOST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL /* handle service NodePorts; NOTE: thi                    s must be the last rule in the chain */

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.5           172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:8086
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.5           172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:8083

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8086 to:172.17.0.5:8086
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083 to:172.17.0.5:8083

Chain KUBE-NODEPORT-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-NODEPORT-HOST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.0.1           /* default/kubernetes: */ tcp dpt:443 redir ports 43104
REDIRECT   udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.0.10          /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp dpt:53 redir ports 60423
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.0.10          /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp dpt:53 redir ports 35036
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.176.182       /* kube-system/monitoring-grafana: */ tcp dpt:80 redir ports 41454
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.17.81         /* kube-system/heapster: */ tcp dpt:80 redir ports 40296
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.228.184       /* kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:http */ tcp dpt:8083 redir ports 39963
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.228.184       /* kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:api */ tcp dpt:8086 redir ports 40214

Chain KUBE-PORTALS-HOST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.0.1           /* default/kubernetes: */ tcp dpt:443 to:10.10.1.84:43104
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.0.10          /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns */ udp dpt:53 to:10.10.1.84:60423
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.0.10          /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp */ tcp dpt:53 to:10.10.1.84:35036
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.176.182       /* kube-system/monitoring-grafana: */ tcp dpt:80 to:10.10.1.84:41454
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.17.81         /* kube-system/heapster: */ tcp dpt:80 to:10.10.1.84:40296
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.228.184       /* kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:http */ tcp dpt:8083 to:10.10.1.84:39963
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.100.228.184       /* kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:api */ tcp dpt:8086 to:10.10.1.84:40214
```

**describe pod --namespace=kube-system monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3-grbs1**

```
Name:                           monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3-grbs1
Namespace:                      kube-system
Image(s):                       gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_influxdb:v0.5,gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_grafana:v2.6.0-2
Node:                           10.10.1.84/10.10.1.84
Start Time:                     Thu, 21 Apr 2016 14:53:31 +0000
Labels:                         k8s-app=influxGrafana,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true,version=v3
Status:                         Running
Reason:
Message:
IP:                             172.17.0.5
Replication Controllers:        monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3 (1/1 replicas created)
Containers:
  influxdb:
    Container ID:       docker://4822dc9e98b5b423cdd1ac8fe15cb516f53ff45f48faf05b067765fdb758c96f
    Image:              gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_influxdb:v0.5
    Image ID:           docker://eb8e59964b24fd1f565f9c583167864ec003e8ba6cced71f38c0725c4b4246d1
    QoS Tier:
      memory:   Guaranteed
      cpu:      Guaranteed
    Limits:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   500Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:              100m
      memory:           500Mi
    State:              Running
      Started:          Thu, 21 Apr 2016 14:53:32 +0000
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
  grafana:
    Container ID:       docker://46888bd4a4b0c51ab8f03a17db2dbf5bfe329ef7c389b7422b86344a206b3653
    Image:              gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_grafana:v2.6.0-2
    Image ID:           docker://7553afcc1ffd82fe359fe7d69a5d0d7fef3020e45542caeaf95e5623ded41fbb
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:      Guaranteed
      memory:   Guaranteed
    Limits:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   100Mi
    Requests:
      memory:           100Mi
      cpu:              100m
    State:              Running
      Started:          Thu, 21 Apr 2016 14:53:32 +0000
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
      INFLUXDB_SERVICE_URL:             http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
      GF_AUTH_BASIC_ENABLED:            false
      GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED:        true
      GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE:       Admin
      GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL:               /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         True
Volumes:
  influxdb-persistent-storage:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
  grafana-persistent-storage:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
  default-token-lacal:
    Type:       Secret (a secret that should populate this volume)
    SecretName: default-token-lacal
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubobjectPath                           Reason                  Message
  ─────────     ────────        ─────   ────                    ─────────────                           ──────                  ───────
  23m           23m             5       {scheduler }                                                    FailedScheduling        Failed for reason PodFitsHostPorts and possibly others
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    implicitly required container POD       Created                 Created with docker id 97a95bd1f80a
  22m           22m             1       {scheduler }                                                    Scheduled               Successfully assigned monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3-grbs1 to 10.10.1.84
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    implicitly required container POD       Pulled                  Container image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0" already present on machine
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    spec.containers{grafana}                Pulled                  Container image "gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_grafana:v2.6.0-2" already present on machine
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    spec.containers{grafana}                Created                 Created with docker id 46888bd4a4b0
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    spec.containers{grafana}                Started                 Started with docker id 46888bd4a4b0
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    spec.containers{influxdb}               Pulled                  Container image "gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_influxdb:v0.5" already present on machine
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    implicitly required container POD       Started                 Started with docker id 97a95bd1f80a
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    spec.containers{influxdb}               Created                 Created with docker id 4822dc9e98b5
  22m           22m             1       {kubelet 10.10.1.84}    spec.containers{influxdb}               Started                 Started with docker id 4822dc9e98b5
```

Don't know what else to share. I can share other information if required. Please help, I couldn't find any solution for this.

### **EDIT**

The response from the command as suggested in the answer below:

```
kubectl attach -it --namespace=kube-system monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v2-c2tj9

J[04/21/16 23:30:19] [INFO] Loading configuration file /config/config.toml

0+---------------------------------------------+
0|  _____        __ _            _____  ____   |
0| |_   _|      / _| |          |  __ \|  _ \  |
0|   | |  _ __ | |_| |_   ___  _| |  | | |_) | |
0|   | | | '_ \|  _| | | | \ \/ / |  | |  _ <  |
0|  _| |_| | | | | | | |_| |>  <| |__| | |_) | |
0| |_____|_| |_|_| |_|\__,_/_/\_\_____/|____/  |
0+---------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To help drill down on what the problem is, I'd recommend seeing if the master is able to reach the pod at all. This'll help determine whether the issue is in your networking setup as a whole or just with the service routing from the master.

You should be able to verify whether the apiserver can reach the pod by `kubectl attach -it --namespace=kube-system monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3-grbs1` and seeing whether it's able to connect. If it can connect, then there's something wrong with the service routing. If it can't, then the master is having trouble communicating with the node.

Comment: Updated the post with the command response. After executing the command the console became unresponsive.

Comment: Ah, that's very good info. That actually means that you were successfully able to attach to the pod, which means that the master is able to talk directly to the pod since attach opens up a connection from your client through the apiserver to the pod.

That means that the problem is in the service proxying configuration somewhere. I'd recommend opening up a github issue against the guide that you used to set up your cluster, and include the kube-apiserver logs (/var/log/kube-apiserver.log on the master) as additional useful information.

Comment: I have already opened the issue on kubernetes github (don't know how exactly to open against the guide, however I have mentioned the guide I am using) and as you said I'll also update it with apiserver logs.